# FreeBSD give ftp user permission to usr/local/www/apache22/data/

Tags: unix, freebsd

I setup a webserver in FreeBSD and need to access it via ftp. I turned on ftpd and when I create a user with **adduser** command it has full access only to /usr/username

I can browse the rest of the server via ftp but everything else is read-only. How do I get write-erase permission for **usr/local/www/apache22/data/** so I can upload files for the web?

Comment: Typically this is done using group permissions. So assign the folder and all its content to the group the ftp daemon uses and grant group write permissions. In addition you need to adjust the umask inside the ftp daemon (whichever you use) to grant group write permissions to all newly created files and directories.

Comment: I did chmod 777 ./  on the /data folder and that did the trick.

Comment: Mode 777 never is a good idea. It is a rough workaround to test something, but it removes all security ideas from file system handling. Actually it is more a statement the sort of: _I cannot figure out how to do this correctly, so I just open everything for everyone_. Works, but insecure and ugly. Anyways, if it's fine for it it's ok, I guess. However you want to take a closer lock at what happens to files and folders newly created, _especially_ if those also have to be written by the http server. In that case, as mentioned, you need to take care of the permission masks.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD supports ACLs on UFS2 and on ZFS that would let you specify access permissions in a way that's more flexible than traditional owner-group-others. See documentation for details:

- [FreeBSD handbook: Access Control Lists](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/fs-acl.html)
- [man setfacl(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setfacl)